# FFmpeg errors "encoding frame failed" and "Can't encode audio frame" when attempting to export from Audacity

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, encoding, manjaro, audacity

Attempting to use Audacity to export any type of audio file that is dependent on FFmpeg (AAC, Opus, etc.) fails with two successive dialog boxes:

> FFmpeg: ERROR - encoding frame failed

> FFmpeg: ERROR - Can't encode audio frame.

ffmpeg 4.4, library versions reported by Audacity are: F 58.76.100 | C 58.134.100 | U 56.70.100

OS is Manjaro 21.0.4 Ornara, kernel 5.10.34-1-MANJARO

I am using Audacity 3.0.2 built from the AUR. This issue appears to be independent of Audacity version as it also occurred with 2.4.1 from the official Community repositories. Under the "Build Information" page of the About box, FFmpeg import and export is said to be enabled.

How might I go about getting FFmpeg exports to work again? Do I need to get ffmpeg's stderr or run it in verbose/debug mode to get more information, and if so, how would I do that?

Comment: Use an older ffmpeg version e.g. 3.0. FFmpeg's API has changed and last time I checked Audacity uses the old API.

Comment: @Gyan I tried a few older versions ranging from 3.4.8 to 4.3.2 and each one broke a different set of applications. VLC would play only audio for any x264/265 videos, some online streaming sites refused to work, etc. Is there any way to force Audacity to use that older version while everything else can use the latest 4.4?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. Tried building the 58 libavformat but was interfering with the ffmpeg actual dependencies.

Just erased that build and went for the Flatpak version, don't hate Flatpaks but in case official repositories fail, Flatpaks are better than Snaps for AUR/Manjaro.